# Is there a DecimalFormat that behaves like Double.toString?

Tags: java, floating-point, formatting

I'd like to find a format string (pattern) for `DecimalFormat` that works like converting a double number to string, e.g. by using `Double.toString(double)`.

Examples:

```
1 → "1.0"
123456.789 → "123456.789"
1e50 → "1.0e50"
```

Does such a format exist?

Comment: Why do you need a `DecimalFormat`? Can you not use a `Formatter` with code `%g` instead?

Comment: @JimGarrison because I'd like to format numbers in a similar way but slightly differently, and I'd like to know if I can use `DecimalFormat` for that (or any other alternative that involves a format string). Also, `Formatter` with `%g` has TOTALLY different results for the examples I gave.

Comment: What about just using `Double.toString()`?  Why does it have to be a `DecimalFormat`?

Comment: @JimGarrison because I'd like to format numbers in a similar way but slightly differently, and I'd like to know if I can use `DecimalFormat` for that (or any other alternative that involves a format string)

Comment: I suggest you [edit] your question and explain EXACTLY the formatting rules you want to achieve.  Since you haven't shared what _"similar way but slightly differently"_ means, I'm not sure how anybody here can help.

Comment: That is irrelevant to this question. I asked a very clear and specific question about `DecimalFormat`, anybody can help by trying to answer it directly (and not by questioning my motives).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've been able to determine so far, there is no single `DecimalFormat` pattern that can emulate `Double.toString` (which seems weird to me), however it can be done with two patterns and a magnitude range, as documented in the [`Double.toString(double)` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString-double-).

Here is a method that seems to do the job:

```
public static String fmt(final double d) {
    final double a = Math.abs(d);
    final boolean normal = a == 0 || a >= 1e-3 && a < 1e7;
    final DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat(normal ?
            "0.0##################" :
            "0.0#################E0");
    return f.format(d);
}
```

It has different results for NaN and infinities, but those can be handled as special cases.